# Recommended way to deploy a war-file to a Tomcat using Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, tomcat, jenkins, deployment, war

I am looking for the golden way how to automatically (re)deploy a **war**-file `myPortal.war` onto a Tomcat server using Jenkins, assuming the Tomcat is running on another machine with a Tomcat-manager running. The relevant powershell build step within my current Jenkins job is the following:

```
$user = "foo"
$pass = "bar"
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$ServerURL = $ENV:Server
$Path = $ENV:WORKSPACE
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpass)
Invoke-WebRequest -URI "$($ServerURL)/manager/text/undeploy?path=/myPortal" 
                  -Method GET -Credential $credential -UseBasicParsing
Invoke-WebRequest -InFile "$($Path)\myPortal.war" 
                  -URI "$($ServerURL)/manager/text/deploy?path=/myPortal&update=true" 
                  -Method PUT -Credential $credential 
                  -ContentType  'application/zip' -UseBasicParsing
```

Here, I used the `undeploy`-command as described by [Tomcat Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Undeploy_an_Existing_Application). **My problem in detail:**

1. Is it really necessary to have the Tomcat-manager-GUI running and the according credential hard-coded into the Jenkins-job? Isn't there a more elegant way than that given that I cannot network-mount my server?
2. Under which conditions **can I leave out the undeployment** before deploying the WAR-file without running into the risk of having remains of the previous deployment lingering around in the directory `myPortal`?
3. Another issue is that the script may fail (due to e.g. wrong credentials) without the Jenkins job failing.

I am aware of the Tomcat-plugin for Jenkins, but this (a) also requires the Tomcat-manager to be running and (b) I am failing to redeploy using a Jenkins **Choice parameter** (neither a `$ServerURL` nor a `%ServerURL` works) which seems to be [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24876) that it is not possible use a parameterized container.

Here are the most relevant related posts, however they did not answer my question:

- [Cannot successfully deploy war file in tomcat using jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561078/)
- [Re-deploying a "versioned" war file from Jenkins to Tomcat fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845225/)
- [Auto-Deploy war file from jenkins without Tomcat's Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519520/)
- [Jenkins auto deploy tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277223/)
- [Jenkins WAR deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829960/)

Comment: You said that you are aware of Tomcat Container Plugin Jenkins, this is the easy way, but tomcat server should be in running, this might  be enough for it..

Comment: Good point, thank you Chandra! **Open detail:** Does that plugin really guarantee that the previous deployment is fully wiped? Besides, the Jenkins plugin is not available for Tomcat 8, what do I do here?

Comment: you can write curl script to do that so.

Comment: A curl-script would be (from an architectural point) just the same as my PowerShell script above, i.e. I still would have to hard-code password and username, a solution which is not favorable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: The work-around we are currently using is to let some other software do the deployment. The reason for this was not the above-mentioned security-concerns, but a requirement of our customer to use a proprietary software packaging service XYZ of their choice. **All Jenkins does now is to upload the WAR-file using the API of that software packaging service.**

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an older post but I have got it working using Jenkins on a unix server and curl...

Comment: Please expand on your answer to make it more helpful to others